# How to i hide/show user controls in form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to change between different displays for my game. I need to show different screens where a player can choose what they want to play and what difficulty they want it. Before user control, I wanted to use panels but, they were really hard to customize because I need to add a lot of picture boxes, so I got myself user controls.

Now the problem is that panels were easy to manage with the visible property but, I just can't find the way to make user controls visible and later hide them if a button is clicked.

Is there an actual way to change those controls if first, I click the button in the form to make control1 visible, then click the button in control1  to hide control1 and make control2 visible?

the form name is form1 and my current Uc name is UCmilline (info to make it more clear for me cause Im used to video tutorials or live)

Comment: Your userControl inherits from Control, so it has the `visible` property you can use in the same way you were using panels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you don't have a lot of User Control you can use "*Bring to front*" and "*Send to back*" way. But I think this bad way if you have a lot of User Control. for example :

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Control1.BringToFront();   //Control1 will show in front.
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Control1.SendToBack();    //Control1 will send to back.
  {
```

- I think this good :)
- There are two button in tool bar if you use Visual Studio .. You can use it .

Answer (score 0):

Either

- Set your `Control.Visible` property or if you need to do this on a batch of controls put them in a panel and set the `Panel.Visible` property
- Or use something like a tab control, and position it to hide the tabs